dotnet CLI build : Display all build properties
I want display all available properties in dotnet build. I found a similar question, but about MSBuild :

List all Defined MSBuild Variables - Equivalent to set

I tried the solution to define the log level to diagnostic :
dotnet build --verbosity diagnostic

But it don't diplay the properties.
